# Is there any assembly language debugger for OS X?

Tags: macos, assembly, debugging

So i was wondering if there is any? I know afd on windows but not sure anything about mac?

And this his how i am using nasam on the following code: nasm a.asm -o a.com -l a.lst

```
[org 0x100]
mov ax, 5
mov bx, 10
add ax, bx
mov bx, 15
add ax, bx
mov ax, 0x4c00
int 0x21
```

On windows i know a debugger name afd which help me to step through each statement but not sure how i can do this using gdb.

And neither i am able to execute this .com file, am i supposed to make some other file here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why are you writing 16-bit code that makes DOS syscalls? If you want to know how to write asm that's applicable to your OS, take a look the code generated by "`gcc -S`" on some C code...  (Note that code generated this way will have operands reversed, and is meant to be assembled with `as` instead of `nasm`)

Further, are you aware what this code is doing?  It reads to me like this:

```
ax = 5
bx = 10
ax += bx
bx = 15
ax += bx
ax = 0x4c00
int 21h
```

Seems like this code is equivalent to:

```
mov bx, 15
mov ax, 4c00
int 21h
```

Which according to what I see [here](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html), is `exit(0)`.  You didn't need to change `bx` either...

But.  This doesn't even apply to what you were trying to do, because Mac OS X is not MS-DOS, does not know about DOS APIs, cannot run `.COM` files, etc.  I wasn't even aware that it can run 16 bit code.  You will want to look at nasm's `-f elf` option, and you will want to use registers like `eax` rather than `ax`.

I've not done assembly programming on OS X, but you could theoretically do something like this:

```
extern exit
global main
main:
    push dword 0
    call exit

    ; This will never get called, but hey...
    add esp, 4
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Then:

```
nasm -f elf foo.asm -o foo.o
ld -o foo foo.o -lc
```

Of course this is relying on the C library, which you might not want to do.  I've omitted the "full" version because I don't know what the syscall interface looks like on Mac.  On many platforms your entry point is the symbol `_start` and you do syscalls with `int 80h` or `sysenter`.

As for debugging...  I would also suggest GDB.  You can advance by a single instruction with `stepi`, and the `info registers` command will dump register state.  The `disassemble` command is also helpful.

**Update:** Just remembered, I don't think Mac OS X uses ELF...  Well..  Much of what I wrote still applies.  :-)

Comment: I think the book which i am using is written primarily for DOS, i have check out how i can use it on mac. Thanks anyway it was helpful.

Comment: I suggest you use DOSBox http://www.dosbox.com/ for playing around with DOS stuff, although you'll need to get a DOS compiler and a DOS debugger too.

Answer (score 7):

Xcode ships with [GDB](https://web.archive.org/web/20110819092406/http://developer.apple.com/tools/gcc_overview.html), the GNU Debugger.
Xcode 4 and newer ships with LLDB instead.

Comment: @JohnClements replaced by LLDB since Xcode 4... in year 2011.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, use GDB, the gnu debugger.  In debugging assembly source, I usually find it useful to load a command file that contains something like the following:

```
display/5i $pc
display/x $eax
display/x $ebx
...
```

`display/5i` will display 5 instructions starting with the next to be executed.  You can use the `stepi` command to step execution one instruction at a time.  `display/x $eax` displays the contents of the eax register in hex.  You will also likely want to use the `x` command to examine the contents of memory: `x/x $eax`, for example, prints the contents of the memory whose address is stored in eax.

These are a few of many commands.  Download the GDB manual and skim through it to find other commands you may be interested in using.

Answer (score 0):

[IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) does work on the Mac after a fashion (UI still runs on Windows; see [an example](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/macdemo/index.htm)).